# How to use 2 versions of JQuery efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app that using JQuery 1.6, this can't be changed. I have a D3 viewer that needs a version atleast 1.8. I have found a solution as follows :

```
<script src='link to jquery 1.10'  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='link to jquery custom 1.10'  type="text/javascript"></script>

var jQuery_1_8_2= $.noConflict(true);
```

So where is use '$', i now use 'jQuery_1_8_2'.

This works great, but i have the plugin JStree.

What i need is a function that basically when the viewer is run it changes every use of JQuery to the newer version. So i dont have to go into the source code of the plugin and change every '$' character to 'jQuery_1_8_2'.

Comment: can you provide a simple sample? how it work and what you want? How you use jstree?

Comment: @Grundy it would take a while, i dont think youll need to know how the plugin works. I just need a way to instead of using a variable as the jquery no conflict i need to have a way to say, after i call this everytime i use '$' use the newer version of jquery

Comment: i think you just use plugin wrong, usually jquery plugins create with function with params like `function($, ...)` and calling line `plugin(jQuery)` so `$` inside plugin - can be not same as outside. So how you include and use/setup jstree?

Comment: that is a really good point, ill have a look now

Comment: [jstree source](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/src/jstree.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order your JS files in a way that when JSTree loads there is only one version of JQuery available, it gets JQuery object only once, so there is no problem changing the value of global `$` \ `jQuery` after it has loaded.

```
<script src="jquery_for_jstree.js"></script>
<script src="jstree.js"></script>
<script>
 var jsTreeJquery = $.noConflict(true);
 </script>
<script src="another_jQuery.js"></script>
<script>
   jsTreeJquery ("...").jstree(...)
</script>
```

You can see this approach working on
http://jsfiddle.net/npd3kc5t/

This works because JSTree follows jQuery advice of [protecting alias and adding scope](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#protecting-the-alias-and-adding-scope).

In other words when the plugin loads, it gets the global `jQuery` reference and creates a local variable `$` only for it, so does not matter what do you do after plugin loaded with global `$` \ `jQuery`.

Comment: this is great. I obviously didnt understand the plugin properly. However when I try call the jstree : """ $jQuery_1_11_3("#list").jstree({"plugins" : [ "wholerow", "checkbox", "sort", "search", "state" ]}); """" i get the error : """" $jQuery_1_11_3(...).jstree is not a function """"

Comment: my variable is $jQuery_1_11_3. And im using version Jquery 1.11.3.

Comment: you should review your jquery/js files loading order

Comment: you were right. I was calling the jstree library after i had set the variable for the jquery library. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery no conflict

```
//new version 
var newJquery = jQuery.noConflict();
//call it like this
newJquery('#example').on('click')......
```

For the old one do the samething

```
var oldJquery = jQuery.noConflict();
```